# Python - Addition of Elements from a list and writing them in a new one

Tags: python

i have got a list like this in Python:

```
List [1, 41, 6, 1, 41, 13]
```

now i want to add the elements and want to write it in a new list like this:

```
newList [42, 48, 49, 90, 103]
```

i hope someone can help me

thanks

Comment: `[sum(a[:i]) for i in xrange(1, len(a)+1)]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters the accepted answer in the dupe seems to yield a different result from what OP wants.

Comment: @timgeb: they only need to skip the first value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters For OP's list im getting `[1, 102, 41, 61, 6, 55, 1, 54, 41, 13]`. What and where should I skip?

Comment: @timgeb: the second answer, using `accumulate()`. So `islice(accumulate(input_list), 1, None))`, to include skipping the first result.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, ok, I'm only questioning that this question is a dupe of that other one. The OP in the dupe seems to desire a completely different output.

Comment: Found a better dupe.

Answer (score 0):

With `numpy.cumsum`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = [1, 41, 6, 1, 41, 13]
>>> list(np.cumsum(lst)[1:])
[42, 48, 49, 90, 103]
```